# Filter input metrics in vmagent (prometheus)

Tags: prometheus, config, monitoring, metrics, victoriametrics

I have vmagent with 1 target. It`s scrape 4k+ samples, but i need about 20.
How can I filter unnecessary metrics so as not to store from?

I tried to use this design, but it did not work:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 60s
  scrape_timeout: 60s
  external_labels:
    server_name: vmagent

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "kafka_exporter"
    file_sd_configs:
    - files:
      - kafka_exporter.yml
    params:
      match[]:
        - '{__name__=~"kafka_topic_partitions"}'
```

Comment: I think you need to drop metrics that you don't need via relabeling - see https://docs.victoriametrics.com/relabeling/#how-to-drop-metrics-during-scrape